# make tool generate class file on unity, but cant use these file in time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use Unity to make a game, but first I want to make a tool that does two things:

- Generate class files.
- Call these class files to execute some funciton.

e.g:

Generate a class file like this:

```
class TestClass{
   public void print(){Debug.log("call this function")}
}
```

And execute this class:

```
#use reflection get this class instance,then call "print" function
MethondInfo printFunction = t.GetMethod("print");
printFunction.InvoKe()
```

The problem is, when generating the class, unityEdit can't find these files in time.  I must, in Project view, chose the folder and right click "Show in Explorer", then unityEdit will add these new files to file system.

I think unity should provide some file API that does this, but I can't find it.  What should I do?

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you, it would be helpful for others if you accept that answer. If not, feel free to comment on the answers given, or update your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you add classes to the project by hand using File Explorer, on reentering UnityEditor it will automatically check for new or modified files. If you generate your classes using some kind of Editor script however, you must actively tell the Editor to check.

You can do this by calling AssetDatabase.Refresh from an Editor script, see http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.Refresh.html.